# Use of modular arthemitic to prove identity

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

While studying primes that are either $2^n+1$ or $2^{n}-1$, I noticed this relationship.

$2^{(n-1)/{2}}-(-1)^{(n^{2}-1)/{24}}\equiv 0\mod n$ iff $n$ is prime for $n\ge5$.

My question is, how can I prove this rigorously? I think it can be proved using a modular argument involving the totient function but I'm not clear where to start.

Comment: Is equivalent to what? You need something on the right-hand side of $\equiv$

Comment: Is congruent mod n. That's what it says. Meaning n will only divide the left side if n is prime.

Comment: @e2theipi2026 then you want a zero on the right side

Comment: The exponent of $\;(-1)\;$ isn't always an integer...

Comment: I know. The left side is only an integer if n is a prime. That is the statement I'm trying to make.

Comment: It would be better to use $8$ instead of $24$. Then it is true that if $n$ is an odd prime, your expression is congruent to $0$ mod $n$.  (With $24$ we have to start at $n=5$). I do not think the converse holds.

Comment: @e2theipi2026 Nop. For $\;p=3\;$ the exponent $\;\frac{p^2-1}{24}\;$ isn't an integer.But no worries: after that, $$\;p>3\;\;\text{prime}\;\implies p^2-1=0\pmod3\;\text{and also}\;\;p^2-1=0\pmod8 $$

Comment: Oh sorry, the restriction is >=5 I'll fix that

Comment: Wouldn't this congruence solve Artin's Conjecture for $\;2\;$ being a primitive root modulo $\;p\;$ for infinite primes? In fact, we'd have $\;2^{(n-1)/2}=-1\;$ for all those primes for which $\;\frac{n^2-1}{24}\;$ is odd.

Comment: I knew it was important from the material I was researching. I hope this is so. It was divisibility of 24 that gave me the idea.

Comment: @e2theipi2026 Well, there you go: you prove that congruence and you solve that 89 years old conjecture.

Comment: @Joanpemo : and this is thisone https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots ? if you can write an answer for explaining in a few words how this is a complicated conjecture

Comment: What I observed is that $2^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$ is congruent mod p at the position of the even numbers in $\frac{p^{2}-1}{24}$ and for +1 its the opposite. Putting it all together you get the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be a prime $\ge 5$. There are two cases to examine.

(i) If $n$ is of the form $8k\pm 1$, then $2$ is a quadratic residue of $n$, and therefore $2^{(n-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{n}$. But if $n\equiv \pm 1\pmod{8}$, then $\frac{n^2-1}{24}$ is even, and therefore $(-1)^{(n^2-1)/24}=1$. Thus the desired congruence holds in this case.

(ii) If $n$ is of the form $8k\pm 3$, then $2$ is a quadratic non-residue of $n$, and therefore $2^{(n-1)/2}\equiv -1\pmod{n}$. But if $n\equiv \pm 3\pmod{8}$, then $\frac{n^2-1}{24}$ is odd, and therefore $(-1)^{(n^2-1)/24}=-1$. Thus the desired congruence also holds in this case.

**Remark:** The converse does not hold. For example, let $n$ be the Carmichael number $561$.

Comment: So just to be clear, with my congruence and your proof, is this a solution to the Artin's conjecture? Or what is left to prove exactly?

Comment: It has little connection to the Artin Conjecture, we used properties of quadratic residues, non-residues, not properties of primitive roots.  A primitive root must be a non-residue, but not conversely.

Comment: Refer to comment by joanpemo under post. So this is incorrect? Does this congruence have any significance at all then?

Comment: The congruence is a nice one. It is essentially a restatement of the characterization of the primes that have $2$ as a quadratic residue, non-residue.  But, as I wrote earlier, no real connection with the Artin Conjecture.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @e2theipi2026: You are welcome. I have added an example where your congruence holds but $n$ is not prime.  There may be smaller ones.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to change that big iff to a smaller more humble if. :)

Comment: "Most" of the numbers that satisfy your congruence are prime.